# how to extract info from dynamic web page

Tags: selenium, scrapy

after clicking the green button which is view details  i get the pop up window which shows more information . how can i scrape the information inside that pop up window.
i tried to  extract info after clicking using selenium but iam getting this error

Comment: We do not have enough information to answer your question. Please [edit] your question to include a [repro].

Answer (score 1):

You have an iframe there that its causing problems:
You can get the data from that pop up like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time 

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="D:/chromedriver.exe")

driver.get('http://www.directoriomedicomexicano.com/Esp_Medicas/MedicosListado.aspx?P1=37&P2=ORTOPEDIA%20Y%20TRAUMATOLOGIA') 

#get all 'Ver detalles'
view_more_buttons = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//img[contains(@onclick,'ShowWindow')]")

#click on the first one
view_more_buttons[0].click()

#switch to the iframe
iframe = driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ASPxPopupControl1_CIF1")
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)

#wait 3 seconds
time.sleep(3)

#get the text from the table
table = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//table[@align='center']")

print(table.text)
```

[image]

Comment: the code is working till opening the window but not printing any text from the table                   getting an error message saying can't find the element

Comment: hmm weird, maybe the pop doesnt load fast enough. can you add a time.sleep(3). I'll edit the code.

Comment: hey can u explain why do we need to add sleep 3 seconds

Comment: did it work with the added 3 seconds? the table's text its not populated instantly on slow network connections so getting the text as soon as the table appears results in an empty "text"